# iPhone app to follow/navigate an imported .gpx

Tags: iphone, gps

Is there an iPhone app that allows one to follow an imported .gpx track, in a car navigation-like way?

The apps I found so far, like Trails, can only display the track on a map. What I am looking for is a "download-and-forget" experience for my bike trips. I want to import a track and just look at my iPhone to tell me in which direction is the next waypoint, or how can I get back on track if I get lost.

Comment: See also: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/iphone-app-to-follow-navigate-an-imported-gpx

Answer (score 3):

[Gaia GPS](http://www.gaiagps.com/iphone_and_ipad/) is what you're looking for. Costs $20 USD [on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gaia-gps/id329127297?mt=8), but the best at what it does.

Comment: Are you sure it does navigation along a GPX? I perused the descriptions on the Web page and in the App store and couldn't find anything about such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't drive, ride, hike or use GPX myself, but here's an idea, using [TomTom](http://www.tomtom.com/):

Get [GSAK](http://www.gsak.net/) (thanks to [tomtom's forums](http://www.tomtomforums.com/tomtom-go-630-720-720t-730-730t-740-750/16910-gpx-tomtom.html)) to convert the GPX to a TomTom file format and [add it](http://www.tomtomforums.com/tomtom-iphone-navigator/18780-how-add-custom-voices-pois-iphone-without-jailbreaking.html) (thanks to [groundspeak forums](http://forums.groundspeak.com/GC/index.php?showtopic=250553)) to your [iPhone's TomTom](http://www.tomtom.com/en_gb/products/mobile-navigation/).

Answer (score 0):

I know; old question. But I happen to have been looking too, and the closest thing I found  was [Co-Rider](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/co-rider/id538095358?mt=8).

Turn by turn spoken instructions, and allows GPX import.

It seems to be geared (pun intended) towards bicycles, so your mileage may vary (pun intended).